# Cannot create a Pull Requests from Visual Studio Code Web-Based editor [GitHub version]

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

I recently started using VS Code online from within GitHub.  I see there is a **Create a Pull Request** option, but it does not show any repositories/branches.

What do I need to do to make this work?

[image]

Comment: For a PR, you need a fork or branch. Do you have one?

Comment: This is a standard repo with a "main" branch and the "123" branch.  Notice in the screenshot that the branch is called "123".  I just made it in my personal GitHub to test this out.  I also have a "Corporate" account for my job, and the same issue occurs.  I thought the issue might have been related to some "corporate" policy.